# Post in Twitter from iOS 6

Tags: ios, twitter, ios6, sharing

I want to configure send data to facebook and twitter. I have a big article. In facebook goes fine, but Twitter is empty. I understand that because of the amount of data greater than 140 characters.

How do I check to see if the data to send to facebook send all article. And if the data is sent to Twitter sent only 140 characters.

Thank you very much

```
    NSArray *activityItems;
    NSString *myText = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
    NSLog(@"my text -> %@",myText);
    NSString *path = ([self.data isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d",self.key,selectedCategory]:self.key);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", path];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:string];
        activityItems = @[myText, image];
   UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple / quick and dirty check would be to just count the number of characters in your string, like this:

```
if ([string length] <= 140) {
   // Good for Twitter
} else {
   // Too long
}
```

Twitter does shorten URLs, which means that sometimes you may be allowed longer tweets than 140 characters. If you were presenting the social sheet directly you could use the `setInitialText` method to check whether it was an acceptable length, but you're using the activity view controller instead.

Comment: How to know the user has selected twitter or facebook?